# Bottle shaped indent

Tags: wood

I'm wanting to make a wine bottle rack where the bottle lays sideways. I've got an image of what I'm after but there would only be one groove and it would  be larger to accommodate 2 bottles laid in it - approximately 70cm long. The groove can indent the whole length of the wood or start shallow then deeper as in the photo, either way is ok.

I'm making two versions: one pine, one oak. I haven't figured out how to create the bottle groove consistently so that it looks more professional.

I don't have heavy machinery like a lathe, but do have a router, drill, sander and Dremel. I don't have specialised woodworking hand tools but will buy one if that's the best solution.

Does anyone out there have any advice?

[image]

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "one wood, one oak". Also, what sort of tools do you own or know how to use? Is this hand-tools only, or do you want to use a machine tool? [Edit] the question and put these details in there.

Comment: A rounded groove like that is definitely the domain of the router. However, for a groove big enough for a wine bottle, you're really looking at a shaper. A shaper is nothing more than a _big_ router permanently mounted in a heavy table with the bit pointed up. You're going to need to make a 3-4" wide groove and that, even at multiple shallow passes is way beyond anything even a _large_ hand-held router could handle.

Comment: Chisels might not be a bad thing to try.  Would take longer than power tools, but would get you exactly what you want and will be cheaper.

Comment: This is entirely doable by hand methods — after all it's how this sort of thing would have been done historically since they had no choice. But in addition to the skills needed to do it consistently (which you may not care to or have time to develop) it may require the creation of one or more speciality tools, such as a purpose-shaped a card scraper. [contd]

Comment: So the rational way to do this today for the leisure woodworker is to route the bulk of it away with a coving bit, then do the 'ramp' portion manually. You could design and build a simple carriage thing that would allow you to do the whole thing via router, with a sort of ramp at the end so it lifts out of the cut. But obviously this will need some prototyping and trial and error to get right.

Comment: Thank you, that's helped me to understand more how to complete the task. I've seen a
cove core box router bit being used to create a rounded groove - would that work alongside the homemade jig? I was thinking a 2" one passed a few times would maybe work?

Comment: @Graphus, I think your comment is the best candidate for an answer given the tools available. Hog out the majority of the cove with a router or a table saw using the appropriate jog, finish by hand with carving chisels and scrapers. the details about both routers and saws work as "milling" machines might be touched on, as I suspect a full cut with a large radius coving bit might be tricky. But, at the end of the day, there is going to be some experimentation here.

Comment: If you had a table saw, you could cut nice grooves using a technique which is shown by The Woodsmith Shop. Here is a video showing how to do it: https://www.woodsmithshop.com/episodes/season10/1005/  Sorry to exasperate you by recommending use of a tool that you don't have.

Comment: I know there are rules about "+1", but +1 to the tablesaw idea. If you don't want to watch that video, google "cove on table saw"

Comment: Does anyone want to turn the "saw as a coving mill" comment into an answer?

Comment: Check out a fretboard radius jig that  guitar makers use with a router to craft the curved tops of fretboards. This is a template attached to a router and rides on pipes to create a convex curve. It would seem like the same idea could be used to make a concave curve in your case by just changing the template accordingly.